# C Bison GLR const stack item

Tags: c, bison, glr

I started writing a simple LR(1) parser with Bison. When processing lists I used a simple implementation of a vector, for example when parsing a list of expressions:

```
tuple-expression-list: expression[first] ',' expression[second] { 
    foo_vector_init(&$$); 
    foo_vector_push_back(&$$, $first); 
    foo_vector_push_back(&$$, $second); }

tuple-expression-list: tuple-expression-list[list] ',' expression[expr] { 
    foo_vector_push_back(&$list, $expr); $$ = $list; }
```

This worked fine. But then the grammar changed and I had to go for the GLR parser. Suddenly the compiler complained about `$list` being constant. I found that for GLR parsers:

1. when the parser splits actions are recorded and not executed until either:

   - all but one parsers have died
   - two parsers are merged
2. One should never modify `yyval` in an action (which is the lookahead).

Questions:

1. when I never have to merge am I sure that only the actions that result in the final parse are executed?
2. Is assigning `$list` to a local variable first a valid fix or should I copy the vector deeply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. when I never have to merge am I sure that only the actions that result in the final parse are executed?

Yes.  [The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/GLR-Parsers.html) specifies that

> *During the time that there are multiple parsers, semantic actions are
>   recorded, but not performed. When a parser disappears, its recorded
>   semantic actions disappear as well, and are never performed.*

The point is precisely that the semantic actions performed are (only) those associated with the actual reductions accepted for the overall parse.

> 2. Is assigning $list to a local variable first a valid fix or should I copy the vector deeply?

It's hard to be sure without knowing anything about your particular vector implementation, or about what other semantic actions are present in the grammar.  Supposing that

- such an assignment produces a shallow copy of the vector (as opposed, say, to a pointer or reference to the existing object), and that
- the preceding contents of the vector are not subject to change in any possible line of reductions that performs the semantic action in question, and that
- the copy, not the original, is presented as the semantic value of the action,

a shallow copy should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `$$` and `$list` are of type `struct vector_t` containins `size`, `capacity`, `element_size` and `ptr`. A assignment would create a copy of those entries, but not copy any of the elements pointed to by `ptr`. Is that what you consider a shallow copy?

Comment: @lars: do the assignment first so you can modify `$$`: `{  $$ = $list;  foo_vector_push_back(&$$, $expr);  }`